# Making a linked list: getting segmentation faults

Tags: c++

I'm practicing how to make a linked list in c++, with the code posted below. Am I allocating the memory wrong? I'm not sure if it's my constructor for node or list causing the error but I keep getting segmentation faults. I'm a beginner and I'm really trying to get a good understanding of memory allocation.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include "list.h"
using namespace std;


int main(void)
{

int option;
list *linked;
linked = new list;




while(1)
{
// menu
cout<<"********************************************"<<endl;
cout<<" what option would you like to use "<<endl;
cout<<" 1.add a node"<<endl;
cout<<" 2.show list"<<endl;
cout<<" 3.delete node"<<endl;
cout<<"********************************************"<<endl;
cin>>option;
//switch for option 
    switch(option)
    {
     case 1 : 
     cout<<"you picked add a node"<<endl;
     (*linked).add_node();
     break;
     case 2 :
     cout<<"you picked show list"<<endl;
     break;
     case 3 :
     cout<<"you picked delete node"<<endl;
     break;
     default:
     cout<<"thats not a valid option"<<endl;
     break;
    }
}

return 0;

}
```

list.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class node
{
private:
node *next;
node *prev;
string note;

public:
// constructor
node();
//gets
node* get_next(void)
{return next;}
node* get_prev(void)
{return prev;}
// setts
void set_next(node* x)
{next=x;}
void set_prev(node* x)
{prev=x;}
};
class list
{   
private:
node *head, *current, *tail;


public:
//constructor
list();

void add_node(void);
};

 node::node(void)
 {
string x;
cout<<"hi"<<endl;
//set front and back null
next=NULL;
prev=NULL;

//write the note
cout<<" what note would you like to write in the node"<<endl;
cin>>x;
note=x;
}
list::list(void){
//start the list pointing to null
head = tail = NULL;
}
void list::add_node(void)
{


//make first node
    if(head=0){
 head = new node;
 cout<<"1"<<endl;
 }
//make 2nd node
else if((*head).get_next()==0){
 cout<<"2"<<endl;
 node* temp;// buffer
 temp= new node;
 (*head).set_next(temp);
 (*head).set_prev(temp);
 (*tail).set_next(head);
 (*tail).set_prev(head);

 }





 }
```

---

Comment: `if(head=0)` would always return `true`

Comment: @Rahn Actually it will always be false and it will additionally set `head` to NULL.

Comment: In addition to the actual pointed out, lack of consistent indentation makes this code pretty much unreadable.

Comment: This also lands into one of my favourite lands of nasty. Thanks to `using namespace std;`, if any of the includes also includes  or forward defines `std::list` you're in for a bad time. Your `list` will have to fight it out with `std::list` for ownership of the name.

Comment: *I'm a beginner* -- Yet you took on an endeavor (making a **working**, **bug free** linked list) that is meant for advanced programmers.  Not to throw cold water on this, but I have yet to see a beginner get this correct without tons of help from experienced C++ people.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are getting the fault when adding the nodes.

The problem I see is that after the first insertion, you have properly allocated a head, but nothing has been done for the tail. In the next insertion because your head is valid, you go into the 'make second node' code block and here you are trying to de-reference the tail member which is not yet initialized.

Comment: Thank you guys for the feed back it helped, I also appreciate you telling me about my indentation.